# GoogleMap.addMarker throws null exception

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I was trying to create a search bar for my custom Google map app, but the app force closes every time I try to search a location. It looked like that I did everything correctly, sequentially speaking. Thing is, when I tried to search for a location it just force closes the app, back to the main menu.

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/google_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/sv_loc"
        android:queryHint="Search for a place or location..."
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Java file :

```
package my.maptestapplication;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap GMap;
    SupportMapFragment SMapFrag;
    SearchView searchView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchView = findViewById(R.id.sv_loc);
        SMapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                String Loc = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                List<Address> addressList = null;

                if (Loc != null || !Loc.equals("")){
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(Loc, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    LatLng Lat_Lng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                    GMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Lat_Lng).title(Loc));
                    GMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Lat_Lng, 10));
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        SMapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
```

Logcat :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uIzbJvkyefEby9Yo2vqiOQwByXl_G1uq/view?usp=sharing

I would assume that if it succeeds, a map marker would appear and it would highlight the location I've entered on the search bar. Would there be anyone to help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you are trying to set the marker `GMap` is null.

Thats why you have to use the `onMapReady` event and set your `GMap` variable.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   GMap = googleMap;
}
```

You can read about `onMapReady` event [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback)

Comment: Thank you! I'm just beginning on this thing and your answer fixed the problem straight away. Cheers!